# What bonus does elemental and armor piercing damage give?

Tags: warframe

I have Armor piercing, Electrical, Freeze and Fire damage mods for my weapons.

Do they apply any other bonus than the extra damage?

Do they provide some special bonus vs. certain enemies or is it the same for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around on the [GuideScroll Warframe guides](http://guidescroll.com/2013/01/warframe-damage-mechanics-guide/) I have found the following information:

GRINEER: Takes bonus damage from Armor Piercing.
CORPUS: Takes bonus damage and gets staggered by Electricity.
INFESTED: Takes bonus damage and some gets staggered by Fire, some are immune to Electricity.

Freeze damage dose 200% damage to shields where all other damge type do 100% damage.

Most enemies will recive a bonus resist based on there level that is subtracted from your damage.

Damage is listed as Normal hit/Weakpoint hit, for most that is Body/Head.

---

## GRINEER

Everything is armored except for melee Grineer.
Normals include trooper, Lancer, etc.
Heavy include Bombadier and Gunner.
Shield Grineer takes damage as Normals, but recives 2 levels less resistance.
Commander-normal is the same as Heavy but immune to electrical/fire damage, AP/freeze not tested.

```
        Normal      Armor Piercing  Fire        Freeze      Electrical
Sawmen  100%/300%   100%/200%       100%/200%   100%/200%   100%/200%
Normals 33%/100%    150%/300%       37.5%/75%   16.5%/33%   20%/40%
Heavy   66%/200%    100%/200%       50%/100%+   50%/100%    50%/100%
```

---

## CORPUS

Crewmen are armored.
They are Staggered by Electricity.
Moa's weak point is there midsection/gun.

```
        Normal      Armor Piercing  Fire        Freeze      Electrical
Crewmen 81%/0%      100%/2000%      33%/100%    75%/200%    160%/400%
Moa     100%/200%   50%/100%        50%/100%    50%/100%    200%/400%
Osprey  100%        100%            100%        100%        200%
Cameras 100%        100%            100%        100%        200%
```

---

## INFESTED

Normals include Chargers, Leapers, Runners, etc.
Ancient heads/bodies and Crawler bodies are armored.
Normals and Ancients are Staggered by Fire.
Crawlers have 3 areas of damage Body/Legs and Arms/Head.
Ancients have 3 areas of damage Body/Head/Lower legs and Arms.

```
                    Normal          Armor Piercing  Fire            Freeze          Electrical
Normals             100%/200%       50%/100%        200%/400%       100%/200%       50%/100%
Nauseous Crawler    66%/100%/200%   50%/50%/100%    125%/200%/400%  50%/100%/200%   50%/50%/100%
Crawler             50%/100%/200%   50%/50%/100%    100%/200%/400%  50%/100%/200%   50%/50%/100%
Ancients            25%/75%/100%    100%/200%/100%  37.5%/75%/200%  25%/50%/100%    0%
```